# Are puppet cities counted towards the limit of 3 imposed by the "Bollywood" achievement in Civilization V?

Tags: achievements, civilization-5

> **Bollywood**
>
> As Gandhi, win a cultural
>   victory with 3 or fewer cities in your
>   empire.

Do puppet cities count towards this limit or not?

I'd assume they probably are ([since you do get culture from Puppet cities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/is-it-possible-to-win-culturally-in-civilization-v-with-only-one-city/8270#8270)), but it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can confirm this. I had three cities as India and later conquered and puppetted two cities thinking I'd be good, but did not get the achievement after a cultural victory.

I got it in another game where I got a culture victory with India with only my capital.

Comment: I guess this answer also verifies that you can get a culture victory with a single city. Thanks!

Comment: which difficulty level did you get the single city victory on?

Comment: The game where I failed to get the achievement was one of my first and it was in the tutorial, so the lowest difficulty. The game I did get it was on Prince, on an Archipelago map. I explain it [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/is-it-possible-to-win-culturally-in-civilization-v-with-only-one-city/8320#8320)