# How much does each city increase the cost of social policies?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization 5, each city you build increases the cost of new social policies by some percentage, based on the current map size.

[This question mentions +30% for duel sized maps.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/is-it-possible-to-win-culturally-in-civilization-v-with-only-one-city) I'm assuming this is correct?

What are the percentages for other map sizes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is taken straight from the XML files included with Civ V:
(Updated for the June 2011 patch, where all of them were reduced by 50%)

```
 <Type>WORLDSIZE_DUEL</Type> 
  <NumCitiesPolicyCostMod>15</NumCitiesPolicyCostMod> 


  <Type>WORLDSIZE_TINY</Type> 
  <NumCitiesPolicyCostMod>15</NumCitiesPolicyCostMod> 


  <Type>WORLDSIZE_SMALL</Type> 
  <NumCitiesPolicyCostMod>15</NumCitiesPolicyCostMod> 


  <Type>WORLDSIZE_STANDARD</Type> 
  <NumCitiesPolicyCostMod>15</NumCitiesPolicyCostMod> 


  <Type>WORLDSIZE_LARGE</Type> 
  <NumCitiesPolicyCostMod>10</NumCitiesPolicyCostMod> 


  <Type>WORLDSIZE_HUGE</Type> 
  <NumCitiesPolicyCostMod>7.5</NumCitiesPolicyCostMod>
```

So it's 15% for all but the largest two map sizes.